# Precise line height in pre

Tags: html, css, pre

I have a `<pre>` element and I need the line height to be *exactly 15px* (so it lines up with something else).

I've played around with `font-size` and `line-height` but they seem to interact in non-obvious ways. Can someone explain how they work and if it is possible to force exactly 15px line heights?

Comment: whats wrong with height: 15px ?

Comment: My first option would be `font-size: 15px; line-height: 1;` but surely it can't be that easy.

Comment: @CuongHoang: `height` applies to entire DOM elements as far as I understand. Each line of a `<pre>` is not a separate element.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález: Yes unfortunately that does not work. It's a little more than 15px. Seems to be 16px. :-/

Comment: pre {
 line-height: 15px;
 font-size: 20px;
} Doesn't it work?

Comment: No. The `font-size` seems to override the `line-height` somehow.

Comment: Being long time user yourself and with envious rep., but still without a MVCE, therefore think again.

Comment: I have an enviable rep because I ask and answer helpful questions not because I go around nit-picking rules.

Answer (score 1):

Ok it turns out that @ÁlvaroGonzález's suggestion does work in a simple test case I made. For some reason it is really giving me a line height of 16px in my actual file, so something else weird must be going on.

Shown here for 10px because coincidentally the default line height in Chrome seems to be exactly 15px.

```css
.ruler {
  width: 50px;
  height: 10px;
}

pre {
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 1;
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div style="display: flex; align-items: flex-start;">
  <div>
     <div class="ruler" style="background: red;"></div>
     <div class="ruler" style="background: green;"></div>
     <div class="ruler" style="background: blue;"></div>
     <div class="ruler" style="background: red;"></div>
     <div class="ruler" style="background: green;"></div>
     <div class="ruler" style="background: blue;"></div>
     <div class="ruler" style="background: red;"></div>
     <div class="ruler" style="background: green;"></div>
     <div class="ruler" style="background: blue;"></div>
  </div>
  <pre>
Why would
somebody mark
this question
as off-topic?
Whoever did
this you are
what is
wrong with
StackOverflow.
  </pre>
</div>
```